# How do I make p:dataTable in ui:composition more reusable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets, el

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.4 and I have a series of .xhtml for the dataTables on a page.  I would like to use one .xhtml for all the tables on the page and use ui:param when including that .xhtml for each kind of dataTable. If I have the following code fragment:

```
<p:dataTable id="invoiceTable" emptyMessage="Pick a category from the drop down" 
    rows="10" var="invoice" value="#{editorUIBean.invoices}" scrollable="true"
    scrollHeight="180" editable="true" rowKey="#{invoice.seqId}"
    ...
```

So imagine I have an .xhtml for invoices, one for cash tendered, one for sales taxes, etc and each .xhtml is identical except for the property in the backing bean and the IDs and variable names.  So if I genericify the fragment above, WHAT_DO_I_REPLACE_THIS_WITH to make it work?

```
<p:dataTable id="#{tableId}" emptyMessage="#{emptyMessage}" rows="10" var="#{rowId}"
    value="#{editorUIBean[dataProperty]}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="180"
    editable="true" rowKey="#{WHAT_DO_I_REPLACE_THIS_WITH[rowKey]}"
    ...
```

So if this code is included in editableTable.xhtml and I use it as follows:

```
...
<ui:include src="editableTable.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="tableId" value="invoiceId"/>
    <ui:param name="emptyMessage" value="Pick a category from the drop down"/>
    <ui:param name="rowId" value="invoice"/>
    <ui:param name="dataProperty" value="invoices"/>
    <ui:param name="rowKey" value="seqId"/>
    ...
</ui:include>
....
```

So basically I am asking, how do I get the variable invoice from rowId instead of the string "invoice"?  In JSF or PrimeFaces is there an eval() function?  Can I do something like eval(rowId)[rowKey]?

Forgive me for not wording my question very well, I am a JSF/Primefaces newbie and don't know the terminology.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use `[server-side-includes]` tag. That's a completely different matter. As to your concrete question, your include file would already fail on `var` which disallows EL. How did you get that far? Have you ever thought about a hardcoded `var` the usual way? That would immediately solve your current problem.

Comment: Thanks, since the var is scoped to the dataTable, I was able to use the same var name for each include, works now, thanks